# Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have already used AndroidJUnitRunner on another project following the instruction [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/AndroidJUnitRunnerUserGuide).

Now I'm trying to use it in another project but I'm having problems.

I added:

```
testCompile('com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1') {
    exclude group: 'junit'  // junit:junit-dep conflicts with junit:unit
}
```

what happens is that Android studio shows the error:

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1

and asks me to install a new package. I accept and AS shows:

```
Loading SDK information...
Refresh Sources:
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources

Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Installing Android Support Repository, revision 15
    Installed Android Support Repository, revision 15
  Done. 1 package installed.
```

But then when I try to sync I get the same error again

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1

and AS asks me to install it again.

I checked that the package is already installed.

Comment: `com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1` has been replaced by `com.android.support.test:rules:0.3`. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Testing/JUnit4

Comment: but on the other project it still works

Comment: I fear it has got to do with the fact that I'm not using apply "plugin: 'com.android.application'" as you can see from "testCompile" instead of "androidTestCompile". I'm checking it now

Comment: "I'm not using apply "plugin: 'com.android.application'"" -- well, you need to use `com.android.application` or `com.android.library`, otherwise there is no point in trying to use Android's instrumentation testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied your comment @CommonsWare, Just to have quick access.

`com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1` has been **replaced by** `com.android.support.test:rules:0.3`

[See github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Testing/JUnit4](http://See%20github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Testing/JUnit4)